# Does there exist a family of functions $(g_i)$ such that $\int_A g_i(x)g_j(x)dx=0 \Leftrightarrow i\nmid j \land j\nmid i$

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-number-theory

$A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and should not depend on $i$ and $j$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions like "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this site. Therefore try to improve your question with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2962594/edit). Improving could consist of providing some context concerning your task or by adding what you have tried so far and where did you struggle :)

Comment: Some observations on the question: the problem is essentially specifying a restriction on the Gramian matrix of $(g_i)$ - and in fact any symmetric positive semidefinite matrix is possible as a Gramian matrix in a function space.  So, the question reduces to: is there a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix such that the $ij$ entry is zero if and only if $i$ and $j$ are incomparable by divisibility?